# Statistical Datacollection with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm building an application with Nodejs and Mongodb to scan Stackoverflow for new content, and find hot and trending topic, and I need to know what way to do this, because I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly as I come form MySQL and my gut feeling tells me there is something different here.

I'm not actually scanning Stackoverflow, it's just easy to use as an analogy, but nonetheless I have Posts, I have Comments, and Users who posted the thread (disregarding users who posted comments atm).

My initial solution was to create three tables (collections):

- Posts - where I store all the information about the post
- Post Stats - where I store all the dynamic information about post (number of comments, overall score, etc') once every X minutes
- Users - where I store information about the users who have posted the Posts

Essentially I want to be able to query the database with "Give me the top Users of today", and "give me the history of this post" to create a sort of graph how this post behaved (ranked, scored, commented, etc') over time.

What's the correct way of doing something like this with Mongodb? Should I store the Post Stats as part of the Posts documents?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go for a hybrid solution here.

It is inevitable that you want some kind of aggregated data on the `post` for all time. So within the `post` I would house an extra subdocument that contains stats for all time:

```
stats: {
    views: 456, // Just an example
    vote_ups: 5,
    vote_downs: 4,
    rank: 1, // vote ups minus vote downs
    comments: 5,
    answers: 6
}
```

Then for individual periods of time I would use `post_stats` the way you explain creating a document like:

```
{
    post_id: 45,
    // etcera for minute by minute changes
    time: ISODate()
}
```

Using the `post_id` (or `_id` rather) to query for the graph you wish to make. Since MongoDB is good at scaling horizontally you will be taking full advantage of it here.